# git grep alias produces a syntax error in git config file

Tags: git

I use the following command to display too long lines in my code:

```
git grep -n '.\{130,\}' *.*pp
```

But, when I try to create a git alias with it like this:

```
    checkcpplines = grep -n '.\{130,\}' *.*pp
```

I get the following error message:

```
fatal: bad config line 15 in file /[...]/.gitconfig
```

I suppose the problem comes from the curly brackets, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes (`\`) in Git config file lines need to be escaped, as they are themselves escape characters.  So:

```
checkcpplines = grep -n '.\{130,\}' *.*pp
```

is not valid, but:

```
checkcpplines = grep -n '.\\{130,\\}' *.*pp
```

is.

The fact that there are single quotes here is not relevant as Git's quoting rules are *Git's*, not some shell's.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried it your solution but I had gotten a syntax error. I realize it was a different error (no '_' in alias name). It works well with double '\' and no '_'.

Answer (score 0):

can you try `alias checkcpplines="grep -n '.\{130,\}' *.*pp"` ?

Comment: It works with the following bash alias `alias checkcpplines="grep -n '.\{130,\}'"` and the folowwing call `checkcpplines \`find -name "*.*pp"\``.

Comment: And is this what you wanted?

Comment: No I want an alias in the .gicongif file, to call `git checkcpplines`.